# Oracle SQL Check between 2 Tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables that I need to validate some information, for example:

**Table A (GTM_LICENSE):**

```
License ID (PK) - License Category
123 - PURCHASE
456 - SALES
```

**Table B (GTM_LICENSE_INVOLVED_PARTY):**

```
License ID (PK) - Involved Party Type
123 - SUPPLIER X
456 - CUSTOMER X
```

However, I need to validate the following:
A Purchase License must always have at least one SUPPLIER record. A Sales License must always have at least one CUSTOMER record.

I can execute 2 different queries or even just 1 query that checks these 2 conditions at once. It doesn't matter. However, my expected result would be "1" if the condition is true (a Purchase License has Supplier OR a Sales License has Customer) or null if the condition is false.

I'm trying to run the following query ut it's not working for me.

```
SELECT 1 FROM GTM_LICENSE L
INNER JOIN GTM_LICENSE_INVOLVED_PARTY LI
ON LI.LICENSE_GID = L.LICENSE_GID 
WHERE LI.INVOLVED_PARTY_QUAL_GID IN ('CUSTOMER','SUPPLIER') 
  AND L.LICENSE_CATEGORY_GID IN ('SALES','PURCHASE')
GROUP BY L.LICENSE_GID 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

How can I do this using Oracle SQL? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select l.license_gid,
  l.license_category_gid,
  (select max(1) from gtm_license_involved_party li
         where li.license_gid = l.license_gid
           and ((li.involved_party_qual_gid = 'CUSTOMER' 
                 and l.license_category_gid = 'SALES')
                or (li.involved_party_qual_gid = 'SUPPLIER' 
                    and l.license_category_gid = 'PURCHASE'))
     ) valid_party
from gtm_license l
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would get you the list of licenses that don't meet the requirement:

```
SELECT L.LICENSE_GID
FROM GTM_LICENSE L LEFT OUTER JOIN GTM_LICENSE_INVOLVED_PARTY LI
    ON LI.LICENSE_GID = L.LICENSE_GID AND
        (
                L.LICENSE_CATEGORY_GID = 'PURCHASE'
            AND LI.INVOLVED_PARTY_QUAL_GID = 'SUPPLIER'
        OR 
                L.LICENSE_CATEGORY_GID = 'SALES'
            AND LI.INVOLVED_PARTY_QUAL_GID = 'CUSTOMER'
        )
WHERE
GROUP BY L.LICENSE_GID 
HAVING COUNT(LI.LICENSE_GID) = 0;
```

This might be more straightforward than having the complicated join condition:

```
SELECT L.LICENSE_GID
FROM GTM_LICENSE L
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM GTM_LICENSE_INVOLVED_PARTY LI
    WHERE LI.LICENSE_GID = L.LICENSE_GID AND
        (
                L.LICENSE_CATEGORY_GID = 'PURCHASE'
            AND LI.INVOLVED_PARTY_QUAL_GID = 'SUPPLIER'
        OR 
                L.LICENSE_CATEGORY_GID = 'SALES'
            AND LI.INVOLVED_PARTY_QUAL_GID = 'CUSTOMER'
        )
);
```

This'll get you a result set with the indicator for every license. It's pretty much the same as kfinity's answer. Rather than using an aggregate function to collapse to a scalar value, I'm using a `case` expression which is arguably more readable:

```
SELECT L.LICENSE_GID
    CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM GTM_LICENSE_INVOLVED_PARTY LI
        WHERE LI.LICENSE_GID = L.LICENSE_GID AND
            (
                    L.LICENSE_CATEGORY_GID = 'PURCHASE'
                AND LI.INVOLVED_PARTY_QUAL_GID = 'SUPPLIER'
            OR 
                    L.LICENSE_CATEGORY_GID = 'SALES'
                AND LI.INVOLVED_PARTY_QUAL_GID = 'CUSTOMER'
            )
    ) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS INDICATOR
FROM GTM_LICENSE L;
```